# If first drop down changes to auto change of second drop down using php

Tags: php

I have two drop downs, one is repositories list where lists not get from database
another one drop down is their branchs

if I select "a" repo option another drop down should show their branches and user change his mind select "b" option second drop down should show their branches

how can done this using php without using database ?

Comment: Would you please show us what you've tried and be more specific on what you don't manage to do ? What are the results you've had ? Why aren't they what you expect ? What do you expect to get ? Maybe juste by answering these questions you will get your answer all by yourself

Comment: We aren't here to write a code for you. Try something and show us your code and examples(if required) if you got stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you want to create something like this:

[image]

I assume that you are aware of all consequences from not using DB for this, so I skip this part.

You will have to use some Javascript, and to make it easier - jQuery, that makes two things:

1. Shows the second dropdown after user selects an option from the first one,
2. Updates options in 2nd dropdown when value of the 1st dropdown changes.

So here's your HTML:

```
<select id='dropdown1' name='branch'>
    <option value='it'>IT</option>
    <option value='entertainment'>Entertainment</option>
</select>
<select id='dropdown2' name='branch-sub' style='display:none;'></select>
```

And here's your jQuery / javascript:

```
var options = {
    'it': ["Programming", "Software", "Hardware", "..."],
    'entertainment': ["PC Games", "Movies", "Music", "..."]
    // And so on
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(){
        $('#dropdown2').show();
        $('#dropdown2').html('');
        var opts = options[$('#dropdown1').val()];
        for(var a = 0; a < opts.length; a++)
            $('#dropdown2').append("<option value='" + opts[a] + "'>" + opts[a] + "</option>");
    });
});
```

**Edit (15-03-2018):** I updated the JS code, so it's working now.

Comment: your understand is correct and I need requirement, dynamically I need take git branch names of every repo and  it should shows it in second drop down option

Comment: Yes, so in my example you have to replace the options in first <select> item, and then add options into the first JS variable (array keys must be the same as in value attributes in HTML's <select> element)